# C# Xamarin Forms Listview set BindingContext to nested List

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, binding, nested

I have a classic `ListView` in a `Xamarin Form` and I am trying to bind it's content.
I come from UWP where we use `CollectionViewSource` and here things are a bit different.

XAML

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" 
                Header="{Binding Intro}"
                Footer="{Binding Summary}">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        Padding="10,5,5,10"
                        BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                        <Label Text="~~"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                        <Label Text="~~"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Description}"></TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Background code

```
var results = new List<Matches> {
                new Matches {Name="Xander", Description="Writer"},
                new Matches {Name="Rupert", Description="Engineer"},
                new Matches {Name="Tammy", Description="Designer"},
                new Matches {Name="Blue", Description="Speaker"},
            };
            var header = new List<Titles> { new Titles { Monkeys = results, Intro = "This is a big header", Summary = "This is the end" } };
            header.Add(new Titles { Monkeys = results, Intro = "Shift", Summary = "Yeah" } );
            //BindingContext = header;
            BindingContext = new Titles { Monkeys = results, Intro = "This is a big header", Summary = "This is the end"};

class Matches
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    class Titles
    {
        public List<Matches> Monkeys { get; set; }
        public string Intro { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

As you see on the line commented out, it doesn't bind the List, hence commented out :)
Any idea if it is possible to bind it's content with nested list with multiple headers and items?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why aren't Matches and Titles public classes?

Comment: They are in the same place... It is just a debug

Comment: after re-reading your question I'm really not sure what you're trying to do.  You may want to read up on Grouped ListView.  But in general a LIstView can have multiple items but only a single Header/Footer.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Error? Because I got this code running with no issues.

Comment: Oh I see, you want Nested Listviews, or Grouped Listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data, I think you shoud to display a group data list. 
You can try the following code:

class Matches

```
public class Matches
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

class Titles

```
public class Titles : ObservableCollection<Matches>
{
    //public List<Matches> Monkeys { get; set; }
    public string Intro { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public Titles(List<Matches> list):base(list)
    {
    }
}
```

class MainPage

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Titles> sortedItems { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Matches> items { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.ItemsSource = getData();
    }


    public List<Titles> getData() {

        items = new ObservableCollection<Matches> {
            new Matches {Name="Xander", Description="Writer"},
            new Matches {Name="Rupert", Description="Engineer"},
            new Matches {Name="Tammy", Description="Designer"},
            new Matches {Name="Blue", Description="Speaker"},
        };


        List<Titles> sortedItems = new List<Titles>() {
            new Titles(items.ToList()){ Intro = "This is a big header", Summary = "This is the end" },
            new Titles(items.ToList()){ Intro = "Shift", Summary = "Yeah" },
            new Titles(items.ToList()){ Intro = "This is a big header", Summary = "This is the end" },
        };

        return sortedItems;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
   <StackLayout>
    <ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            x:Name="listView" 
            IsGroupingEnabled = "True">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="40">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             BackgroundColor="#3498DB"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Intro}"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label Text="   "/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Summary}"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Description}"></TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

The effect is as follows:
[image]

Note:

According to my understanding, you want to display these two fields in the position of each group List, right? Then `ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate` will meet  our need.And you can custom the layout of `ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate` as you want,so you can show the `Intro` and `Summary` at the same time.

Comment: In this case public string Summary { get; set; } is not needed here right? It serves at nothing.
It is pretty much what i was trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Plus i see that <Label Text="123...." />
                <Label Text="321...." FontSize="Small"/> are also not used. Why have them there?

Comment: Sorry, I  forgot to remove these code, I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: It worked, please help me by voting up the question so i can keep getting help form here